# Why ICollection<>.Contains ignores my overridden Equals and the IEquatable<> interface?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, equals, c#-6.0

I have an issue with a navigation property in an entity framework project.

Here is the class `MobileUser`:

```
[DataContract]
[Table("MobileUser")]
public class MobileUser: IEquatable<MobileUser>
{
    // constructors omitted....

    /// <summary>
    /// The primary-key of MobileUser.
    /// This is not the VwdId which is stored in a separate column
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember, Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required, Index(IsUnique = true), MinLength(VwdIdMinLength), MaxLength(VwdIdMaxLength)]
    public string VwdId { get; set; }

    // other properties omitted ...

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<MobileDeviceInfo> DeviceInfos { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(MobileUser other)
    {
        return this.UserId == other?.UserId || this.VwdId == other?.VwdId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))return true;
        MobileUser other = obj as MobileUser;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
        return VwdId.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "foo"; // omitted actual implementation
    }

    #region constants
    // irrelevant
    #endregion
}
```

The relevant part is this navigation property:

```
public virtual ICollection<MobileDeviceInfo> DeviceInfos { get; private set; }
```

This is the class `MobileDeviceInfo`:

```
[DataContract]
[Table("MobileDeviceInfo")]
public class MobileDeviceInfo : IEquatable<MobileDeviceInfo>
{
    [DataContract]
    public enum MobilePlatform
    {
        [EnumMember]
        // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming because correct spelling is iOS
        iOS = 1,
        [EnumMember] Android = 2,
        [EnumMember] WindowsPhone = 3,
        [EnumMember] Blackberry = 4
    }

    // constructors omitted ...

    [DataMember, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DeviceInfoId { get; private set; }

    [DataMember, Required, Index(IsUnique = true), MinLength(DeviceTokenMinLength), MaxLength(DeviceTokenMaxLength)]
    public string DeviceToken { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required, MinLength(DeviceNameMinLength), MaxLength(DeviceNameMaxLength)]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required]
    public MobilePlatform Platform { get; set; }

    // other properties ...

    [DataMember]
    public virtual MobileUser MobileUser { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The foreign-key to the MobileUser.
    ///     This is not the VwdId which is stored in MobileUser
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember, ForeignKey("MobileUser")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MobileDeviceInfo other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return DeviceToken == other.DeviceToken;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Bah"; // implementation omitted

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        MobileDeviceInfo other = obj as MobileDeviceInfo;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
        return DeviceToken.GetHashCode();
    }

    #region constants
    // irrelevant
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see, it implements `IEquatable<MobileDeviceInfo>` and overrides also `Equals` and `GetHashCode` from `System.Object`.

I have following test, i've expected that  `Contains` would call my `Equals` but it does not. It seems to use `Object.ReferenceEquals` instead, so won't find my device because it's a different reference:

```
var userRepo = new MobileUserRepository((ILog)null);
var deviceRepo = new MobileDeviceRepository((ILog)null);

IReadOnlyList<MobileUser> allUser = userRepo.GetAllMobileUsersWithDevices();
MobileUser user = allUser.First();

IReadOnlyList<MobileDeviceInfo> allDevices = deviceRepo.GetMobileDeviceInfos(user.VwdId, true);
MobileDeviceInfo device = allDevices.First();
bool contains = user.DeviceInfos.Contains(device);
bool anyEqual = user.DeviceInfos.Any(x => x.DeviceToken == device.DeviceToken);
Assert.IsTrue(contains); // no, it's false
```

The second approach with `LINQ`'s `Enumerable.Any` returns the expected `true`.

If i don't use `user.DeviceInfos.Contains(device)` but `user.DeviceInfos.ToList().Contains(device)` it also works as expected since `List<>.Contains` uses my `Equals`.

The actual type of the `ICollection<>` seems to be a `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>` but if i use following code that uses also a `HashSet<>` it again works as expected:

```
bool contains = new HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>(user.DeviceInfos).Contains(device); // true
```

So why are only references compared and my custom `Equals` is ignored?

**Update**:

even more confusing is the result is `false` even if i cast it to the 
`HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>`:

```
 // still false
bool contains2 = ((HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>)user.DeviceInfos).Contains(device);
// but this is true as already mentioned
bool contains3 = new HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>(user.DeviceInfos).Contains(device);
```

**Update 2:**: the reason for this really seems to be that both HashSets use different comparers. The entity-framework-HashSet uses a:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer
```

and the standard `HashSet<>` uses a:

```
GenericEqualityComparer<T>
```

That explains the issue, although i don't understand why entity framework uses an implementation that  ignores custom `Equals` implementations under certain circumstances. That's a nasty trap, isn't it?

---

**Conclusion**: never use `Contains` if you don't know what comparer will be used or use  [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) with the overload that takes a custom comparer:

```
bool contains = user.DeviceInfos.Contains(device, EqualityComparer<MobileDeviceInfo>.Default);  // true
```

Comment: `ICollection<T>` itself won't do anything - it's just an interface. What implementation is being used? Can you reproduce this without using EF?

Comment: @JonSkeet: it's not using lazy loading, the type of it is actually a `HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>`. That's what so confusing. Look at the last paragraph. No sql is generated.

Comment: Given your hash code is based on a mutable property, what happens if EF adds the items to the HashSet and *then* sets the property value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: So if it's just a `HashSet<T>`, you should be able to reproduce this without getting EF involved at all, right? A [mcve] would really help here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter compare `((HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>)user.DeviceInfos).Comparer` to `new HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>(user.DeviceInfos).Comparer`, I bet you will see the first one is using a custom comparer created by EF that ignores your `IEquateable` and the 2nd is using the default comparer that will use the `IEquateable`.

Comment: @CharlesMager: this is just the entity class, i can't make it readonly because entity framework will complain. Thats why i've added the resharper hint

Comment: @JonSkeet: ok, i'll try to provide one. I didn't know if it was entity framework related when i've asked this question, so i've shown this code. But i doubt that it's reproducible if i use a `HashSet<T>` since my test already covers this case and it returns `true`. See my **Update**

Comment: One thing you *may* find is that it's a matter of the equality comparer buried in the `HashSet`. You may need to debug in to find that...

Comment: If you're getting your initial collection via EF, you're likely getting code-generated subclasses of your entities, correct? And those subclasses would likely have their own Equals / GetHashCode implementations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not sure I follow. I meant that if the `MobileDeviceInfo` was added to the HashSet by EF before `DeviceToken` was set by EF, then trying to find it later would fail (as in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IgpJeA)).  However, I've just noticed that it's a string so would likely throw a null reference exception if this was the case...

Comment: Well, it looks like it is either something to do with `HashSet<T>` working with its own (different) comparer or EF proxy objects creation, that ignores all other class members except properties and fields, while constructing proxy objects.

Comment: Is `user.DeviceInfos` a `HashSet<MobileDeviceInfo>` or is it a subclass of mentioned hash-set?

Comment: @JonSkeet (and others): thanks, you're right. It's actually using a different comparer, entity framework uses a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer` which name is self-explaining. I still don't understand the reason for this pitfall.

Comment: I love (in the ironic sense) how even the best questions get down votes.  It's so hard to ask questions on this site!

Comment: Referring to my prior comment, I wonder what would happen if you took any given object from your EF-obtained collection, created another object that matches on your key field, and then invoked entityFrameworkObject.Equals(anotherObject). Would that be true. If it is false, then it makes the issue of the HashSet comparer moot, I would believe.

Comment: I was trying to make a repo myself, but once I got one Charles pretty much wrote what I was going to write from my findings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the EF source, you might stumble on [`CreateCollectionCreateDelegate`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/602bc779baa598fecf6f1ad9b94d76e8d30a9c15/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/Internal/PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.cs#L309), which seems to be called as part of hooking up navigation properties.

This calls [`EntityUtil.DetermineCollectionType`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/602bc779baa598fecf6f1ad9b94d76e8d30a9c15/src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/EntityUtil.cs#L92) and returns a `HashSet<T>` as the type if that is compatible with the property.

Then, armed with `HashSet<T>`, it makes a call to [`DelegateFactory.GetNewExpressionForCollectionType`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/602bc779baa598fecf6f1ad9b94d76e8d30a9c15/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/DelegateFactory.cs#L163) which, per the code and the description, handles `HashSet<T>` as a special case and passes it an [`ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/602bc779baa598fecf6f1ad9b94d76e8d30a9c15/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer.cs) in the constructor.

So: the `HashSet<T>` EF creates for you isn't using your equality implementation, it uses reference equality instead.

Comment: Thanks. Although i really don't understand why entity framework wants to use a `ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer` in that case. That's a nasty trap.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe it is using it because because it wants the `ICollection<T>` to have fast cache lookups, It can't guarantee that the default comparer will be well behaved for that function. You thought it was a List at first anyway, so just use the `Enumerable.Contains` overload [that takes in a comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in `EqualityComparer<MobileDeviceInfo>.Default`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: so as a rule of thumb: never use `Contains` if you don't know what the actual type of the collection is and what comparer it uses, otherwise you'll get into hot water.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would agree with that statement.

Answer (score 3):

> *Why ICollection<>.Contains ignores my overridden Equals and the IEquatable<> interface?*

Because there is no requirement from the implementors of the interface to do so.

`ICollection<T>.Contains` method MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Determines whether the ICollection<T> contains a specific value.

And then

> **Remarks**
>
> Implementations **can vary** in how they determine equality of objects; for example, List<T> uses Comparer<T>.Default, whereas Dictionary<TKey, TValue> allows the user to specify the IComparer<T> implementation to use for comparing keys.

*Side note: Looks like they messed up `IComparer<T>` with `IEqualityComparer<T>`, but you get the point :)*

> *Conclusion: never use Contains if you don't know what comparer will be used or use Enumerable.Contains with the overload that takes a custom comparer*

According to the `Enumerable.Contains<T>(IEnumerable<T>, T)` method overload (i.e. without custom comparer) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using the **default** equality comparer.

which sounds like your overrides will be called. But then comes the following:

> **Remarks**
>   If the type of source implements ICollection<T>, the Contains method in that implementation is invoked to obtain the result. Otherwise, this method determines whether source contains the specified element.

which conflicts with the initial statement.

It's really a mess. All I can say is that I fully agree with that conclusion!

Comment: This is... disturbing. Almost as incomprehensible as my own code :)